# What are files/directories naming conventions in linux?

Tags: unix, filenames

Is **this_option** more common than **thisOne**?

Comment: Given how short are most command names and directories, e.g. `cat` for concatenate or `lib` for libraries, I think that the answer to your question would be `to` :-)

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, you might find [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) to be an interesting read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditional folders have names like `bin`, `lib`, and `etc`.  Files have names like `init`, `ls`, and `fstab`.  Probably because when unix was born, memory was so limited that saving 4 bytes was a good idea.

Capital letters were rare.  Not sure why.  The shift key had not been invented yet?

So, `this_option` would be the traditional choice.

In modern times, memory is not a problem.

The system does not require any particular convention.  Any character is allowed except for the `/` and the `NUL` character.

I hate programs that do not work properly if I have a space in my file name.  I should be allowed to use spaces if I want.

A dirty trick is to use a non-printable character in a file name.  If you cannot easily type the file's name, it is difficult to do anything with it.

Comment: *"If you cannot easily type the file's name"* - Say hello to `ls -b`

Answer (score 4):

The general convention would be *thisoption*.

Comment: butisn'tthisreallyhardtounderstand?

Comment: or if you really want to be perverse, youCouldDo_something_like-this

Answer (score 0):

As a child of the Unix family, convention would give `to` or `opt`.

If your file has a GNU licence, you could name it `gopt`.